# react native flatlist item is not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to make my flatlist a reusable component but i get an error

```
item is not defined.
```

How can i let my onpress function have access to item inside my reusable component?

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';



export const WebsiteFlatlist = (props) => {
    return(
        <FlatList
        data={props.data}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={props.onPress}
            >
                <View>
                    <View>
                        <Text>{item.location}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
    />

    )

};
```

**Usage:**

```
<WebsiteFlatlist data={places} onPress={() =>{this._onPress(item.location)}}/>




 _onPress = async (places) => {
        console.log(places)
    };
```

Comment: you are not passing item to onpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the item and should directly pass a function to onPress props.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';



export const WebsiteFlatlist = (props) => {
    return(
        <FlatList
        data={props.data}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={props.onPress.bind(null, item)}
            >
                <View>
                    <View>
                        <Text>{item.location}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
    />

    )

};
```

Usage:

```
<WebsiteFlatlist data={places} onPress={this._onPress}/>

 _onPress = async (places) => {
        console.log(places)
    };
```

Comment: this worked, why is the first argument  null on the bind?

Comment: @obumoon for bind method first parameter is to provide context for function. In this case we don't want to bind context that's why it is null.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onPress` function, you should do this:

```
onPress={this._onPress}
```

In this way, you are passing the `_onPress(location)` function as a callback down to your flat list.

Answer (score 0):

Only pass the functional reference in your `<WebsiteFlatlist onPress={this._onPress}>`. While in the common component make some changes.

1. Separate the renderItem component.
2. Use function to renderItem inside the component.

```
const renderItem = (item) => {
return (
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>props.onPress(item)}>
   <View>
       <View>
           <Text>{item.location}</Text>
       </View>
   </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
)}

<FlatList
   data={props.data}
   keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
   renderItem={
       ({ item }) => (this.renderItem(item))
   }
/>
```